Thumb rotation won't follow IK control and weight painting issue with feet when posing
The bigger picture is the left wrist, after I rotated the IK controller a bit. the two smaller pictures show the deformation on the shoe even though the two bones connected to it have weight.

As you can see in the bigger picture on the left, the thumb isn't rotating with the IK controller for some reason. I tried putting a copy rotation on the long bone that leads to the thumb but that didn't work, it just made it rotate really weird. I thought maybe it might be a hierarchy issue that's why I have it highlighted in the box but I have no idea honestly.
On the smaller pictures on the right, you can see the deformation on the shoe when I moved the foot to the right, I am very new but I thought it was fairly well weight painted so I don't understand why the geo just lags behind like that when it already has weight attached to it.

hello could you please share your file?

yes, i would love to, how could i do that? its my first time on here lol. I could just send it to your personal email?

read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/

can i just send to u personally? it says 30mb max is allowed, my project is 265mb

Only share the part with the problem

Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is harder to read and may be considered rude. Please use the [edit] button below the post to change your text into regular case.

im sorry, i have no idea how to do that, i tried zipping it but i could only get it down to 81mb

or use another platform like workupload and share the link

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/0clg97xw8ub2y9yxqarpz/B0II-full-IK-444.blend?rlkey=wsd2yjwka88ygpnfykbedwhi1&st=tgd4w20t&dl=0

let me know if that works

work upload wasn't working at all

I'm a bit lost with complicated armatures but for example it seems like the thumb bone called DRV_Thumb.L needs to be parented to IK_CTRL.L, I haven't tested the rest, the foot seems to be a problem of weight, also you should not use so many faces for a character that you want to animate, instead build a low-poly and add a Subdivision Surface to round its surface

Thanks for the modelling tip. I tried parenting DRV_Thumb.L to  IK_CTRL.L and it didn't work, what did u parent it to? (object, automatic weights, enveloppe weights, bone). Did you parent it and it worked? If you could u send me back the corrected folder ?(on both thumbs just in case it doesn't work here)
